# Unable to get value from paper-input

Tags: polymer-1.0

```
     <question-chrome question="{{question}}">
      <paper-input label="{{question.Description}}" id="answer" name="answer" type="number">
      {{question.Description}}
      </paper-input>
    </question-chrome>
```

Where question-chrome.html has the followign code:

```
<template>
    <div class="questioncontainer {{question.Type }}" style="padding-top:10px;"> 
        <div class="questiontext">
            <span class="questiontitle">{{question.Title}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="questionanswers">
            <content select=".questionanswers"></content>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I am using the above paper input, when I am trying to get the values from this, I cannot find the value anywhere. the question element/object, I can get and see every other item's value of the question object. How would I get the value of what is put into the input field? in this case, the value was 3323.
this:

The code to retrieve it I have tried all of these:

```
this.$.answer.value;
```

And the results through developer tools in chrome result in:

```
Object
AdditionalProperties:null
Answers:Array[0]
Code:720061
Description:"Monetary marks ...."
ExtensionData:null
HasAnswers:false
HasChildren:false
Id:"9999dcc3-d3eb-40cf-8414-05ae385e11cf"
IsDefault:true
IsDeleted:false
.....so on and so forth
```

I went through all of these and did not find it. It is a numeric type of field, so not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Could you show some more code? What you are trying to do should work. Take a look at [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/PImTL597uEON2FxyDzQ6?p=preview)

Comment: Added the outside code to that paper input, and the question-chrome element we created.

Comment: Did you check the plunkr?

Comment: Yes. I did...and like you said, it looks like my code should work, but answer does not show up in my list.

Comment: It seems I was missing the value={{valuegoeshere}} property. Now I can see the data.